# nest: build a QueryContainer request with must and a should constraint

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I try to build an elasticsearch request with a must and a should request 
my target request is this bellow:

```
POST /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
         "match":{"field1":{"query":"word1"}}
      },
      "should":{
        "match":{"field2":{"query":"word2"}}
      }
    }
  }}
```

I wrote:

```
 var queryContainer = new QueryContainer();
 queryContainer &= new MatchQuery() { Field = "field1", Query = "word1" };
 queryContainer |= new MatchQuery() { Field = "field2", Query = "word2"};


var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<type>
        {
            Query = queryContainer
        };
```

but it produces me :

```
POST /index/type/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "should":[
        {"match":{"field1":{"query":"word1"}}},
        {"match":{"field2":{"query":"word2"}}}]
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know  what should I write when building my QueryContainer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using operator overloading here is not that helpful; I think in this case, constructing the `bool` query is clearer

Object Initializer Syntax

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Document>()
{
    Query = new BoolQuery
    {
        Must = new QueryContainer[] { new MatchQuery() { Field = "field1", Query = "word1" } },
        Should = new QueryContainer[] { new MatchQuery() { Field = "field2", Query = "word2" } }
    }
};

client.Search<Document>(searchRequest);
```

or Fluent API

```
client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(fi => fi
                .Match(m => m
                      .Field("field2")
                      .Query("word2")
                )
            )
            .Should(sh => sh
                .Match(m => m
                      .Field("field1")
                      .Query("word1")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer helped me to understand bool query with must and should using object initialiser.